# Add button to HTML page which updates table information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xml

I have created a table as below and have an onclick function that updates the score information when clicked. I feel that isn't very efficient though and would prefer to avoid the repetition of id's in the table and the listing of getElementbyId aspects of my function.

**Secondly I would rather the data update form a text, json, xml or database file rather than being hardcoded into the javascript function.**

My table looks like this:

```
</div>

    <div id="table">
      <table id="mytable"> 
                            <table width="100%"> 
                            <td style="vertical-align:top"> 
                                <td> 
                                      <table width="99%" border="4"> 
                                      <tr><th>Team </th>
                                          <th>Score</th>
                                          <th>Team </th>
                                          <th>Score</th>
                                      </tr> 
                                      <tr>
                                          <td>Dundalk</td>
                                          <td id="score1">1</td>
                                          <td>Derry</td>
                                          <td id="score2">0</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                          <td>Derry</td>
                                          <td id="score3">0</td>
                                          <td>Dundalk</td>
                                          <td id="score4">0</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                          <td>Drogheda</td>
                                          <td id="score5">1</td>
                                          <td>Dundalk</td>
                                          <td id="score6">2</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      </table> 
        </div>

<div>
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
  <div>

    <p>Click the button to update scores.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Update Scores</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML = "3";
    document.getElementById("score2").innerHTML = "1";
    document.getElementById("score3").innerHTML = "4";
    document.getElementById("score4").innerHTML = "2";
    document.getElementById("score5").innerHTML = "6";
    document.getElementById("score6").innerHTML = "7";
    }
    </script>

    </div>
```

I have created this basic xml file which I would rather update the table scores with:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<score>

<scores>
  <team>"Dundalk"</team>
  <score>3</score>
</scores>

<scores>
  <Team>"Drogheda"</Team>
  <score>2</score>
</scores>

<scores>
  <Team>"Derry"</Team>
  <score>0</score>
</scores>

</score>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure I answered this question already... looks like a school project question.

Comment: Sorry Chris if I missed your answer. I did post a question a few hours ago but it wasn't precise enough so I have narrowed it down and re-posted for the sake of clarity. I don't really know anything about javascript so I am struggling to make any progress at all. I have managed to build my table and general page layout etc. but just need to figure out how to add this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this happen you can add class-tags to all the elements you want to change. Then in Javascript you can create a function that puts all these elements in an array to be changed easily.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Table Content</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">          
            <table id="mytable" width="100%">
                <td style="vertical-align:top">
                    <tr>
                        <th> Team </th>
                        <th> Score </th>
                        <th> Team </th>
                        <th> Score </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Dundalk</td>
                        <td class="score">1</td>
                        <td>Derry</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Derry</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                        <td>Dundalk</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Drogheda</td>
                        <td class="score">1</td>
                        <td>Dundalk</td>
                        <td class="score">2</td>
                    </tr>
                </td>
            </table>            
            <button type="button" onclick="changeContent(0)">Add Point to Dundalk in Dundalk vs. Derry</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript (can be imported from another file too, in example it's inline):**

```
<script>
    var scoretable;

    function initializetable(){
        scoretable = document.getElementsByClassName("score");
    }

    function changeContent(element){
        initializetable();
        scoretable[element].textContent = "NEW";
    }        
</script>
```

*NOTE:*
In the example I call the initialize() function when trying to change content, but it's better to call this function earlier, for example when loading the page and not call it when pressing a button.

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background: black;   
}

#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    top: 20%;
    bottom: 10%;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
}

table{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In the example i've put just one button that calls the changeContent() function to change the first element that has the score-class (remember counting from 0!). This could ofcourse be changed to another element by changing the parameter value. Also you could choose to make a button for every element to change it's value.

Comment: This does sound like what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Svanderwoude can I ask you to give an example using my code above for assigning the tag to the score section of the table? I understand in principle how this works but don't know how to break it down within a table.

Comment: <td id="score_dundalk">0</td>

Comment: Well, if you would want to change the scores in the table you should give all the corresponding table-elemnts a class. So for example to make the title editable the code would be this: <th class="scoretitle">Score</th>. By having a button: <button onclick=changetitle()>Change</button> you call the function changetitle() in either an imported file or inline javascript. This function would then contain the line: document.getElementById("scoretitle").innerHTML = "New Score Title"; By adding if-statements you could ofcourse decide what the new content should be depending on its current content.

Comment: Thank you for your on-going help svanderwoude. So I have edited my code above - does this look right to you. By doing this I should now be able to use javascript via an imported file to run once the button is clicked to automatically change the score numbers?

Comment: Oh sorry, i wasnt clear enough. This is indeed what i meant, but it should be done for every cell you want to edit, with different class names. I think there might be a better solution by iterating through all rows in a column, but i cant test that at the moment. Tomorrow I will look imto simplifying it, since giving every cell an id/class isn't the most elegant option. So i hope that you got enough time to wait for that solution, otherwise you could give every element a different class name, e.g. "1","2". Then call the onclick function with the classname as parameter.

Comment: Sorry savanderwoude this is going over my head a little now. I can wait until tomorrow if you want to come back to me then. I will continue to work on it through for a few hours to try and make some progress on creating the javascript etc.

Comment: @savanderwoude do you happen to know when you might be able to look at this today?

Comment: Yes i will be able to do that. Though im currently at University, ill look into it in about 3-4 hours. Already did a bit

Comment: Following on from your advice last night I have made the appropriate changes and gotten the results I want. However like you said it's not very elegant and really appreciate any refinement you suggest.

Comment: Great, i will update my answer once ive found a better solution.

Comment: I changed the answer to contain example code and some simple styling, i hope youll understand it.

Comment: Very clear svanderwoude. Thank you for you time and help with this.